# Display array values(if array name and string name is same)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to display the corresponding array values depending on string(function return) the string name and array name is same, in angular 4 or 6

I have array A and B:

```
A = ['aaa','arrr','aeee','aqqqq','awwww','axxxx','azzz'];
B = ['cc','sss'];
```

If function return string A, I can list a A array value on template and same as for 
if function return B...

Comment: its not service code, it's simple think but don't know how to do this,
i have a function it return a-z values dynamically if function return D i can display D array values and if function return Z i will display Z array value, for easy purpose i name a array and string  as same(function return string)

Comment: maybe provide a plunkr/stackblitz...
(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtqchr)

Comment: If A and B are in an object: `const values = {A:[],B:[]}` then you can use [the bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to get A or B: `values[someFunctionReturningStringAorB()]`

Comment: why simply has a variable displayArray, and equal to A or to B (this.displayArray=A //or this.displayArray=B) and use {{displayArray}} ?

Comment: @C4mps you should be nice to the new comers

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question properly this is what you are trying to achieve.

`const filteredresult = A.filter(word => word === strvar);`

(**strvar** would be the string return variable from your function)

for eg:

```
A = ['aaa','arrr','aeee','aqqqq','awwww','axxxx','azzz'];
const filteredresult = A.filter(word => word === 'aaa'); 
console.log(filteredresult);
```

Comment: please do not use `var` as variable name (not even in examples). it is a statement for declaring variables.